# Upload file using iFrame for IE9

Tags: javascript, html, json, iframe, internet-explorer-9

Html:

```
<form id="formLogo">
<input type="file" id="logo" name="logo" accept="image/x-png, image/gif, image/jpeg" />
</form>
```

javascript:

```
  var myForm = new FormData();
  myForm .append("file", $("#logo").files[0]);
  myForm .append("type", "company");
  myForm .append("accountId", "3124234");
  $.ajax({
      url: '/efrcetrdmbo/app/file/upload',
      data: myFormData,
      dataType: 'text',
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      type: 'POST',
      success: function (data) {
          alert("sucess");
      }
  });
```

FormData is not supported in IE9. I want to use iFrame to upload file and some other data with it.

Comment: Too broad. Are you actually asking to provide you with an implementation? There are many examples out there, check yourself.

Comment: If I would have got an right explaination on implementation, it would be required to post a question.  Kindly, point to some example if that are known to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of having the iframe in html, creating it before upload and than deleting.

Providing correct url, files are uploaded.

JS:

```
function fileUpload(form, action_url) {
    var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
    iframe.setAttribute("id", "frame");
    iframe.setAttribute("name", "frame");
    iframe.setAttribute("width", "0");
    iframe.setAttribute("height", "0");
    iframe.setAttribute("frameborder", "0");

    form.parentNode.appendChild(iframe);

    iframeId = document.getElementById("frame");

    var eventHandler = function () {

        if (iframeId.detachEvent) iframeId.detachEvent("onload", eventHandler);
        else iframeId.removeEventListener("load", eventHandler, false);

        if (iframeId.contentDocument) {
            content = iframeId.contentDocument.body.innerHTML;
        } else if (iframeId.contentWindow) {
            content = iframeId.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
        } else if (iframeId.document) {
            content = iframeId.document.body.innerHTML;
        }

        setTimeout('iframeId.parentNode.removeChild(iframeId)', 200);
    }

    if (iframeId.addEventListener) iframeId.addEventListener("load", eventHandler, true);
    if (iframeId.attachEvent) iframeId.attachEvent("onload", eventHandler);

    form.setAttribute("target", "frame");
    form.setAttribute("action", action_url);
    form.setAttribute("method", "post");

    form.submit();
}
```

Html:

```
<form>
    <input type="file" name="file" /></br>
    <input type="button" value="upload" onClick="fileUpload(this.form,'url'); return false;" >
</form>
```